# remove columns in export to excel javascript

Tags: javascript, excel

Does anybody knows how to achive this?
I have my html table with some columns with display none, and with javascript i have a export to excel button...all works well, but e excel file generated i also have columns that are with display none...i give to those columns a class (named notToExport), how can i generated the excel file without those columns?

```js
function exportTableToExcel(teste, filename = 'contacorrente'){

    var downloadLink;
    var dataType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
    var tableSelect = document.getElementById(teste);
    var tableHTML = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
    
    
    // Specify file name
    filename = filename?filename+'.xls':'excel_data.xls';
    
    // Create download link element
    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    
    if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
        var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', tableHTML], {
            type: dataType
        });
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);
    }else{
        // Create a link to the file
        downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + tableHTML;
    
        // Setting the file name
        downloadLink.download = filename;
        
        //triggering the function
        downloadLink.click();
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="exportTableToExcel('teste')">export to excel</button>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row col-md-12 custyle">
    <table id="teste" class="table table-striped custab">
    <thead>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right" style="display:none;">Ver por reguralizar</a>
        <tr>
            <th class="notToExport" style="display:none;">Email</th>
            <th>date</th>
            <th>old date</th>
            <th>Document</th>
            <th>number doc</th>
            <th>debt</th>
            <th class="notToExport" style="display:none;">debf</th>
            <th>cred</th>
            <th class="notToExport" style="display:none;">credf</th>
            <th class="notToExport" style="display:none;">obs</th>
            <th class="notToExport" style="display:none;">erpid</th>
            <th>result</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        
            <tr>
                <td class="notToExport" style="display:none;">hfhaskdhf@gmail.com</td>
                <td>14-10-1977</td>
                <td>16-10-1977</td>
                <td>document</td>
                <td>123</td>
                <td>245</td>
                <td class="notToExport" style="display:none;">245</td>
                <td>12</td>
                <td class="notToExport" style="display:none;">12</td>
                <td class="notToExport" style="display:none;">hfksdfhjhdsf</td>
                <td class="notToExport" style="display:none;">gsdfgjhfj</td>
                <td>43</td>
                
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="notToExport" style="display:none;">hfhaskdhf@gmail.com</td>
                <td>14-11-1977</td>
                <td>16-11-1977</td>
                <td>document</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>25</td>
                <td class="notToExport" style="display:none;">24</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td class="notToExport" style="display:none;">2</td>
                <td class="notToExport" style="display:none;">hfksdfhjhdsf</td>
                <td class="notToExport" style="display:none;">gsdfgjhfj</td>
                <td>3</td>
                
            </tr>
           <tr>
                <td class="notToExport" style="display:none;">hfhaskdhf@gmail.com</td>
                <td>14-12-1977</td>
                <td>16-12-1977</td>
                <td>document</td>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td class="notToExport" style="display:none;">4</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td class="notToExport" style="display:none;">2</td>
                <td class="notToExport" style="display:none;">hfksdfhjhdsf</td>
                <td class="notToExport" style="display:none;">gsdfgjhfj</td>
                <td>3</td>
                
            </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
            <tr>
               <th class="notToExport" style="display:none;">Email</th>
                <th colspan="4">TOTAL</th>
                <th class="notToExport" style="display:none;"></th>
                <th class="notToExport" style="display:none;"></th>
                <th class="notToExport" style="display:none;"></th>
                <th>24</th>
                <th class="notToExport" style="display:none;">debf</th>
                <th>44</th>
                <th class="notToExport" style="display:none;">credf</th>
                <th class="notToExport" style="display:none;">obs</th>
                <th class="notToExport" style="display:none;">erpid</th>
                <th>434</th>
                
            </tr>
         </tfoot>
            
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the JS selector "getElementsByClassName" and remove them all from the DOM before exporting your data to Excel.

```js
function exportTableToExcel(teste, filename = 'contacorrente'){

var downloadLink;
var dataType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';

// Find all items that need to be removed
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("notToExport");

// Loop through items and remove from the DOM
for(var i=0; i < elements.length; i++)
{
    elements[i].remove();
  
}

var tableSelect = document.getElementById(teste);
var tableHTML = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');


// Specify file name
filename = filename?filename+'.xls':'excel_data.xls';

// Create download link element
downloadLink = document.createElement("a");

document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);

if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
    var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', tableHTML], {
        type: dataType
    });
    navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);
}else{
    // Create a link to the file
    downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + tableHTML;

    // Setting the file name
    downloadLink.download = filename;
    
    //triggering the function
    downloadLink.click();
}
}
```

```html
    <button onclick="exportTableToExcel('teste')">export to excel</button>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row col-md-12 custyle">
        <table id="teste" class="table table-striped custab">
        <thead>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs pull-right" style="display:none;">Ver por reguralizar</a>
            <tr>
                <th class="notToExport" style="display:none;">Email</th>
                <th>date</th>
                <th>old date</th>
                <th>Document</th>
                <th>number doc</th>
                <th>debt</th>
                <th class="notToExport" style="display:none;">debf</th>
                <th>cred</th>
                <th class="notToExport" style="display:none;">credf</th>
                <th class="notToExport" style="display:none;">obs</th>
                <th class="notToExport" style="display:none;">erpid</th>
                <th>result</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            
                <tr>
                    <td class="notToExport" style="display:none;">hfhaskdhf@gmail.com</td>
                    <td>14-10-1977</td>
                    <td>16-10-1977</td>
                    <td>document</td>
                    <td>123</td>
                    <td>245</td>
                    <td class="notToExport" style="display:none;">245</td>
                    <td>12</td>
                    <td class="notToExport" style="display:none;">12</td>
                    <td class="notToExport" style="display:none;">hfksdfhjhdsf</td>
                    <td class="notToExport" style="display:none;">gsdfgjhfj</td>
                    <td>43</td>
                    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="notToExport" style="display:none;">hfhaskdhf@gmail.com</td>
                    <td>14-11-1977</td>
                    <td>16-11-1977</td>
                    <td>document</td>
                    <td>23</td>
                    <td>25</td>
                    <td class="notToExport" style="display:none;">24</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td class="notToExport" style="display:none;">2</td>
                    <td class="notToExport" style="display:none;">hfksdfhjhdsf</td>
                    <td class="notToExport" style="display:none;">gsdfgjhfj</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    
                </tr>
               <tr>
                    <td class="notToExport" style="display:none;">hfhaskdhf@gmail.com</td>
                    <td>14-12-1977</td>
                    <td>16-12-1977</td>
                    <td>document</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td class="notToExport" style="display:none;">4</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td class="notToExport" style="display:none;">2</td>
                    <td class="notToExport" style="display:none;">hfksdfhjhdsf</td>
                    <td class="notToExport" style="display:none;">gsdfgjhfj</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    
                </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
                <tr>
                   <th class="notToExport" style="display:none;">Email</th>
                    <th colspan="4">TOTAL</th>
                    <th class="notToExport" style="display:none;"></th>
                    <th class="notToExport" style="display:none;"></th>
                    <th class="notToExport" style="display:none;"></th>
                    <th>24</th>
                    <th class="notToExport" style="display:none;">debf</th>
                    <th>44</th>
                    <th class="notToExport" style="display:none;">credf</th>
                    <th class="notToExport" style="display:none;">obs</th>
                    <th class="notToExport" style="display:none;">erpid</th>
                    <th>434</th>
                    
                </tr>
             </tfoot>
                
        </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If you need to retain the original data, clone the table first and then remove the elements from that.

```js
// Create a clone of element with id ddl_1:
let tableSelect = document.getElementById(teste).cloneNode(true);
```